# Unable to connect EC2 instance via ssh

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

What I did:

1. I had an old instance that I no longed needed so I terminated it.
2. Created new RHEL-6.4 micro instance.
3. Created new .pem file from "Key Pairs" section, downloaded and chmoded it to 400.
4. Run the following command from my terminal "ssh -i FILE_NAME.pem ec2-user@ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com"

and I get the following error message:

> Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Key pairs need to be associated with the instance when you create it. Adding a key pair doesn't add it to existing instances.

Essentially, you need to reverse steps 2 and 3 and launch the new RHEL instance with the key pair you made.